# TComboBox list won't drop down when using firemonkey styles in Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, tcombobox

I'm having a problem with the FMX TComboBox component in Delphi 10.1 Berlin (and I've seen it in earlier XE versions as well). The problem is this.

I create a new multi-platform project, drop a TComboBox on an empty form, add a few items to TComboBox.Items, just as you'd do in VCL (this is FMX). Running it and clicking the button of the TComboBox and the items show in a drop down list just as they should.

Next, I drop a TStyleBook on the form, link the form with the StyleBook and load the Copper .style from the Premium firemonkey styles that come with Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Now, when I run the app, the items of the combo box won't show when I click the drop down button. But I can select the items using up and down arrow keys. If I clear the style, the combobox works again.

So, obviously there is either something wrong with the style (have tried other with the same effect) or I'm missing something.

(I also tried to use the Add TListBoxItem from the right-click menu, but the problem remained).

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour with 10.1 Berlin but not with version 10 Seattle, using the Berlin styles in both versions. This problem was already posted at QC several times. (eg [here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14902?jql=text%20~%20%22combobox%22) and [here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14883?jql=text%20~%20%22combobox%22)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll add my vote at QC then. I did search QC but I must have missed them.

Comment: `TComboEdit` seems to work with styles. You could use it temporarily as an alternative.